# Cognitive Service - Vision Read Api Serialization Issue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm noticing a really strange bug using the brand new Microsoft Cognitive Service - Vision Read API via SDK.

[Here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/2afb498089f74080d7ef85eb/console) the API

Currently used SDK is Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision 4.0.0: [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision/4.0.0)

Below my code (mostly taken by the official quick-start reference):

```
[Fact]
        public async Task ReadTest()
        {
            var subscriptionKey = "###########################";
            var imageURI = "############################";

            using (ComputerVisionClient computerVision = new ComputerVisionClient(
                new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(subscriptionKey),
                new System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[] { }))
            {
                computerVision.Endpoint = "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com";
                BatchReadFileHeaders textHeaders = await computerVision.BatchReadFileAsync(imageURI, TextRecognitionMode.Handwritten);

                await GetTextAsync(computerVision, textHeaders.OperationLocation);

            }
        }

private static async Task GetTextAsync(
           ComputerVisionClient computerVision, string operationLocation)
        {
            string operationId = operationLocation.Substring(
                operationLocation.Length - 36);

            ReadOperationResult result =
                await computerVision.GetReadOperationResultAsync(operationId);

            // Wait for the operation to complete
            int i = 0;
            int maxRetries = 10;
            while ((result.Status == TextOperationStatusCodes.Running ||
                    result.Status == TextOperationStatusCodes.NotStarted) && i++ < maxRetries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Server status: {0}, waiting {1} seconds...", result.Status, i);
                await Task.Delay(1000);

                result = await computerVision.GetReadOperationResultAsync(operationId);
            }

            // Display the results
            Console.WriteLine();
            var recResults = result.RecognitionResults;
            foreach (TextRecognitionResult recResult in recResults)
            {
                foreach (Line line in recResult.Lines)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line.Text);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

The issue occurs on the first call of `await computerVision.GetReadOperationResultAsync(operationId);` into `GetTextAsync` method. Basically the error is the following:

> Message: Microsoft.Rest.SerializationException : Unable to deserialize the response.
>   ---- Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Input string '2.7867' is not a valid integer. Path 'recognitionResults[0].lines[0].boundingBox[0]', line 1, position 161.
>
> Result StackTrace:     at
>   Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision.ComputerVisionClient.GetReadOperationResultWithHttpMessagesAsync(String
>   operationId, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision.ComputerVisionClientExtensions.GetReadOperationResultAsync(IComputerVisionClient
>   operations, String operationId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at
>   ****.****.tests.****.GetTextAsync(ComputerVisionClient
>   computerVision, String operationLocation) in

The error is quite simple and alarming. The serializer tries to deserialize a bounding box decimal value '2.7867' into an integer as defined into the corespondent model:

```
namespace Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision.Models
{
    public class Line
    {
        public Line();
        public Line(IList<int> boundingBox = null, string text = null, IList<Word> words = null);

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "boundingBox")]
        public IList<int> BoundingBox { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "words")]
        public IList<Word> Words { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see the model defines BoundingBox as list of integers whilst the vision API returns decimal. How is this even possible? I'm sure I'm missing something cause it seems a huge and noticeable bug...
I checked the quick-start [related github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-vision-csharp-sdk-quickstarts/tree/master/ComputerVision) but it seems stuck at a previous version and almost empty.

### Update

Eventually I found the right github and the issue seems to be tracked. It is related only on pdf files: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/5547

Just opened a ticket with Azure support. Keeping you posted.

### Update 06/20

Received a mail from the Azure support Team. It seems that the newly release [Computer Vision SDK v5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision/) resolves this issue.

Comment: I made a quick test, the field format for `BoundingBox` is different when passing pdf vs png you are right: double vs int! There is a problem in the SDK...

Comment: I added a comment in the Github issue that you found, point to the pull request that should fix it!

Comment: FYI, the PR has been merged, so the SDK may be updated with the relevant field type in its next version